# How reduce wordpress login session timeout time?

Tags: login, logout, session

I want to logout user autometically  when user is idle for more than 10 minutes.That mean suppose user is logged in to a site and user didn't browse any pages for more than 10 mins.when he browse any page after 10mins, it will logout user and redirect to login page.Any Solution?
Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to add your filter hook like this:

```
function myplugin_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $remember ? $expiration : 600;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'myplugin_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

You can add it to your theme’s functions.php file.

Comment: First, thanks for the hooks. I want to know if it is possible to change the background when the user is logout (for security reason) and don't stay on the content page of admin ?

Comment: what are the "99" and "3" and "600" referring to?